# Tag URLs load a single post

Tags: permalinks, tags

I recently rebuilt a WordPress install (maintained database, replaced WordPress/plugins/theme files) after the site was compromised. It is working more or less correctly now, with the exception of tag links:

```
http://www.foo.com/tag/bar
```

forwards to a post tagged with `bar`, rather than displaying a list of posts tagged with `bar`.

I've already replaced .htaccess with a newly generated one from options -> permalinks, to no avail. Google indicates a somewhat similar problem happening in conjunction with DB-Cache, which I do not have installed. Any ideas?

Comment: Which theme/plugins are you using? Try to disable all plugins and set twentythirteen as current theme. Then save permalinks again, and try.

Comment: Have you tried a simple refreshing permalink from Settings > Permalinks and just a click on the "Save Changes". It *can* help solve the problem - I guess. :)

Comment: Yes, Mayeenul, I mentioned doing that in my question.

Answer (score 0):

G.M.'s comment was correct - this was a plugin issue. A legacy pagination plugin ("Multipage Toolkit") I'd replaced from the old install was hijacking permalinks.

The plugin was no longer necessary as WP supports pagination natively. I removed the old plugin, reset permalinks again, and all was well.